# invite in a conference using meetmeadmin?

Tags: asterisk

I am using asterisk 1.8 I currently have:
exten => 1234,MeetMe(1234)

When the client who opens the conference rooms comes in and wants todd new users pressing key 1 for example.?
Can I do that using MeetMeAdmin.How?
 Or the only solution is to use call files?

I am new to this stuff. Need help. Thx

Comment: you should consider @arheops advise so at least you have enough knowledge to understand suggested solution and can give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this code.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/web-meetme/

It already have ALL you asking.
I am sorry, you have learn asterisk more. you are asking questions with no asnwer. You need learn something to answer correct questions.